# cannot resolve symbol 'layout' as in R.layout.xml_name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have read and tried many solutions offered :
Clean, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart android studio, downgrading Gradle from 8.0 to 7.2

I have checked that I properly import the R `import com.example.klinikkitadokter.R;` but the R is red
[image]

and after Downgrading gradle to 7.2 and try to clean rebuild again, it does not work. just does not works

There is a bottom windows that pops up like this
[image]
and that's it, nothing working after that window popups

Checking xml is now very hard since design editor is not working anymore before I successfully sync the project, which I if I try to sync the same bottom windows from above just popups and nothing.

[image: Desgin Editor not working]

nothing works for me. is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Add code always as text never as image

Answer (score 0):

Looks like compatibility issue with Gradle version and Java version you are using.

Did you tried to change Java version you use inside Android Studio.

You provided very limited info but this is my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app package name in java files, app package name in the manifest, the names of the folders in the folder tree, the applicationId and the namespace in the gradle.build of the app. USUALLY all of these must be the same.
EDIT 1: check that the folder layout is not Excluded